# Show Database Items related to user logged (Django)

Tags: python, django, database

In my website when a User log in he's redirected to his profile page. Now I'd like to see all the items he stored in the database. How could I do? Thanks

Here's the views.py. This is the page the user is redirected to after the login

```
class userView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'search/user.html'
```

Html file:

```
<div class="add">
  <div class="posted">

    {% if objects_list %}
    {% for o in objects_list %}
    <div class="container_band">
      <div class=album_band>
        <!-- insert an image -->

        <img src= "" width="100%">

      </div>

      <div class="info_band">
        <!-- insert table info -->
        <table>
          <tr><th><h2>{{o.band}}</h2></th></tr>
          <tr><td> Anno: </td><td> {{o.anno}} </td></tr>
          <tr><td> Disco: </td><td> {{o.disco}} </td></tr>
          <tr><td> Etichetta: </td><td> {{o.etichetta_d}} </td></tr>
          <tr><td> Matrice: </td><td> {{o.matrice}} </td></tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  {% endfor %}
  {% endif %}

  </div>
```

models.py

```
class Info(models.Model):
    utente = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
    band = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    disco = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    etichetta_p = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    etichetta_d = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    matrice = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    anno = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    cover = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', blank=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.band

    class Meta:
      verbose_name_plural = "Info"
      ordering = ['anno']
```

Comment: Please provide your `modesl.py` for the app.

Comment: I've edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a Django view that takes a model and yields the model data.

```py
class userView(ListView):
    model = Info  # assumes it is imported from models
    template_name = 'search/user.html'
```

This will list everything, but you want to limit to the user only. Therefore, filter the output by the user id:

```py
class userView(ListView):
    model = Info  # assumes it is imported from models
    template_name = 'search/user.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = super().get_queryset()
        return qs.filter(utente=self.request.user)
```

Change in your html template `objects_list` to `object_list`.

For further reference, see here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#listview

Comment: Is the user logged in? The code assumes the user is logged, and the username is included in the request, which is used to filter by the username.

Comment: Yes the user is logged. But should I change something in my Html template?

Comment: Just edited, change in your html template `objects_list` to `object_list`.

Comment: Ah just mispelled the word! Thanks a lot!